# In Android Studio 2.2 it does not allow me to drag and drop widget

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

Similar questions had been asked for earlier versions of and I found the most recent was in October 2015. At that time users were no longer be able to drag and drop widget to Design view of activity_main.xml but were able to do so to design view of content_main.xml. Last week (late Sep 2016) I updated Android Studio to 2.2 on macOS Sierra.

The design view is now showing two views for the screen (not sure how to correctly call its name) and I cannot drag and drop widget to either of them. It simply does now allow me to drag any widget from Palette. I tried the menu File/Invalidate Caches/Restart.and it did not help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Sierra i don't know why drag n drop function is not working but in windows android studio 2.2 its working under design Tab, May be some problem when you configure android studio. Please check ones

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Android Studio 2.2 on Windows to try it yet. Possible reasons I can think of includes the following:

1. Android Studio 2.2 does include something that caused this on macOS Sierra. And I happened to updated the Android Studio and mac OS last week;
2. My Android Studio has been installed since probably 1.4 and has been updated for each release. It's not fresh new 2.0 install. Uninstall and reinstall will be a lot of pain and time wasting.
3. My mouse is wireless Logitech M510 which was is connected to a four port StarView DVI KVM switch. But this is a wild guess. It's unlikely the culprit unless one had same issue with windows mouse but not with Mac mouse. I am using 2012 mac mini.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but then I found this useful answer https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211582, and this post give me the solution:

## 11 nan.y...@gmail.com

OK, finally I found how to solve this problem. But it is still strange. I think may be it is still a bug in AS 2.2.

Key is Preferences->Appearance->UI Options->"Drag-n-Drop with ALT pressed only". This is checked as default both in my AS2.1.1 and AS 2.2.

Then 
1) In AS 2.1.1, only I press ALT and then drag items in Project Pane, I can move java class from one package to the other one. In layout editor, I can drag widget from palette to layout without ALT key pressed.

2) In AS 2.2, same as AS2.1, I need to press ALT to drag items in Project Pane. But in layout editor, no matter I press ALT key or not, I cannot drag widget from Palette to layout. The strange is here:
2-1) I uncheck this option, then I can drag item in Project Pane without ALT key pressed, but I still cannot drag widget in Palette. 
2-2) I check this option again, then I need to press ALT to drag item in Project Pane. AND THEN ! I can drag widget in Palette with ALT key pressed. 
2-3) After two step above, if I check this option I need to press ALT to drag a widget from palette. If I uncheck this option I can drag widget directly without ALT press.

Now, dragging widget in Palette works properly in my AS 2.2, but  I still think this solution is wacky. I hope my solution could help to dig out the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can't believe this little setting caused this much pain. Yes, here that there there are so many hidden or easily unnoticed culprits.